# What happens to Athelstan in Season 3?

Tags: character, vikings

When the Vikings arrived in England, they found a small town where monks lived. The Vikings raided and killed many of them. However Athelstan is spared -- because he can speak their language -- and is taken by Rangar back to Denmark.

What has happened to him since then?

Comment: What is the point of asking what happened to him in S3? Have you watched it? Spoilers: http://vikings.wikia.com/wiki/Athelstan#Season_3

Comment: I watched it but I must have missed what happened...

Comment: Yes, I watched it but I am deaf and I watch it with closed captions...I may have missed it but thanks for the link. That helped and that link you gave it is a good site to read...

Comment: I only had time for the 3 major turning points with this character, but I can fill in some details, if desired, when I have some more time. *(The show has top-notch fight choreography, art design and wardrobe, and expressive actors, so you're not missing all that much without sound:)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So much.  So, so much.

He "goes native" for a while and adopts the pagan religion of the Vikings, having traveled with them to [Upsala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uppsala#History).

He hooks up with [Judith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Vikings_characters#Judith) and their progeny is the future King Alfred.  King Ecbert declares the child holy and sends him on a pilgrimage to Rome.

> He finally chooses Christianity and is murdered/martyred by Floki.

Comment: dude, maybe consider a spoiler for the last one? i know it's been a while, but like Usual Suspects and Sixth Sense, it is a major event that maybe people haven't seen yet

Comment: @NicholasAysen They might want to reconsider asking for the fate of a character then.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson when I submitted this answer, it was all spoilered-tagged.  Not sure what happened...

Comment: @DukeZhou I removed them, since you're not supposed to hide the entirety of the answer in invisibility. People who read the answers to this question want to *know* what happened to this guy.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson ic.  is it possible to leave just the first one unhidden?  (imo, that's the least spoiler-ey... :)

Comment: The thrid one really is already more than enough. The point here is, you don't need any spoiler blocks at all, since the asker (and anyone reading further after reading the question) *explicitly asked for it*. There is no point in hiding spoilers when they are the *essence* of the answer. For more information, [this meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/49) is a start, as well as [this one](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/49) for the general policy (summarized in the help center, too). The bottom line is, your answer must make sense without the spoiler blocks.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson fair enough.  Nicholas seemed a little upset, and I had a bad experience once with friends when I alluded to "the prison montage" in Breaking Bad.  *(There it was ironic, b/c these friends got really mad, but they're always texting or going online when they watch TV, and rarely can remember the plots;)*

Comment: @DukeZhou no worries from me. just felt that some unsuspecting user will Google something that somehow ends up here, and will know the fate before making an informed decision to watch the show. has happened to me , as i research before a show, then accidentally become exposed to a spoiler, which, spoils that moment for me. Also reminds me of the time Jennifer Lawrence was being interviewed, stated she hadn't seen that year's season of Homeland, and the reporter promptly spoilt the biggest event for her, when he states that she will watch it later